# Cross-compile gtk crate for Windows

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3

I want to use the [`gtk` crate](https://docs.rs/gtk/0.15.2/gtk/) to write a small gui application for Windows. I was wondering if there is any chance I can cross-compile it from my Linux machine to Windows.

When I try to compile my code against the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target with `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`, I get the following error:

```
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
[...]
  = note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This seems like I'm missing the gtk library files for Windows, but I'm not sure what I should do or how I would get those.

Comment: You have to install the appropriate MinGW libraries. How you do that depends on which distro you are using. For example, on Fedora you'd have to `sudo dnf install mingw32-cairo` to get the 32-bit Cairo library (`mingw64-cairo` for the 64-bit).

Comment: That won't work because I'm on Debian

Comment: Which is why I said *"How you do that **depends on which distro you are using**"*. It was just an example for the distro I'm familiar with. Obviously you will need to find the appropriate packages for Debian.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to say is that there are no such packages for Debian. At least not in the official repos.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mingw-w64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile it by using [this awesome tool](https://github.com/etrombly/rust-crosscompile).

Basically it is dockerized Linux Fedora with all necessary dependencies pre-installed.